# Start Menu shortcuts located in %ProgramData% aren't displayed in Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

Maybe the title is a little confusing, but it is really a simple issue, the Start Menu items for the .lnk files located at "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" ("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs") are missing, the .lnk files are still there but the corresponding Start Menu items have disappeared, the single-user entries (in %AppData%) are unaffected.

I think this is registry related as I have recently used Wise Care 365 to clean the registry and the symptom appeared after the registry cleaning, I have a restore point created before the cleaning that is reasonably up-to-date but I don't want to do a System Restore just yet.

What registry key might be erroneously deleted and what value should it have so that I can fix this issue? I am using Windows 10.0.19042.906 Pro x64 if that helps. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ran something that potentially modified those values, check the registry for the defaults. `Startup` key specifically.

Key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Defaults:
[image]

Comment: Well, unfortunately that didn't help, those values appeared unmodified, and I appended `;%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` to the `Start Menu` value and restarted to no avail. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** There's also a policy setting. **ProcMon** reveals queries for a value named **`NoCommonGroups`** under both:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoCommonGroups

HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoCommonGroups
```

---

---

Ahh...Registry cleaners -- the snake oil of the digital age!

I think @Narzand had the right key but the wrong hive. The locations of common/machine-wide settings are usually found under HKLM. I'd check here first:
[image]

and make sure `%ProgramData%` is still defined.

Comment: The key is also intact, the values unchanged, and `%ProgramData%` is still defined as `cd $env:ProgramData` and `test-path $env:ProgramData` still work, but interestingly its value is `C:\\ProgramData` (double slashes instead of just one).